# Read DataSet Directly Into a Row

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, dataset

Can I get to a specific row and column in a DataSet?  Something like this without a foreach:

```
tnu += ds.Tables["Customer_detalis"].Columns["Bank_Branch"].ToString();
```

This not working for me in winform C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify which row you want to access first:

```
tnu += ds.Tables["Customer_detalis"].Rows[0]["Bank_Branch"].ToString();
```

If you want to add the value from all rows, then do it this way:

```
foreach(DataRow row in ds.Tables["Customer_detalis"].Rows)
{
    tnu += row["Bank_Branch"].ToString();
}
```

Comment: Simple and perfect! You're a wiz!